# Vue - Pass props to a programmatically component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I'm making a sidebar that can have dynamic content, using vuex

So, for exaple, I have this app with a Sidebar.vue that can loads a DynamicContent.vue, how do I pass a prop to that DynamicContent.vue inside

**app.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import store from './store'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import DynamicContent from './components/DynamicContent.vue'

Vue.component('sidebar', Sidebar)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,

    data() {
        return {
            dynamicContent: DynamicContent
        }
    },

    methods: {
        toggleSidebar() {
            this.$store.commit('toggleSidebar', dynamicContent)
        }
    }
})
```

**Sidebar.vue**

Notice: I can't pass my props throught that component tag cause the components can have differents props

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="component" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            component() {
                return this.$store.state.sidebarComponent
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**store.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        sidebarOpen: false,
        sidebarComponent: null
    },

    mutations: {
        toggleSidebar(state, component) {
                state.sidebarOpen = ! state.sidebarOpen
        state.sidebarComponent = component
        },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To dynamically bind props, you can use v-bind this way

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="component" v-bind="componentProps"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            component() {
                return this.$store.state.sidebarComponent
            }
            componentProps {
                return { prop1: 'value', prop2: 123 }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

v-bind takes an object and pass all properties in it as props to component.